# Where to add roaming setting in Windows 8 tutorial - Beginner

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 development. i am following the tutorial provided by the Windows 8 team and i have run across some problem.

Can someone please tell me where i should insert the following code block explained in the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx). (In step 2)

```
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = 
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
        roamingSettings.Values["userName"] = nameInput.Text;
```

I was looking at `MainPage.xaml.cs` but it doesn't have any definition of a TextField. So where should i add this code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is found in MainPage.xaml rather than MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
            <TextBox x:Name="nameInput" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     TextChanged="NameInput_TextChanged"/>
```

The MainPage.xaml.cs is a partial class of the xaml, so any controls declared in the xaml are available from the .cs file.

See the completed example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676794.aspx#view_codexaml).

Comment: Ok, but where should i add the above code. It's not there in the completed code

Comment: That's because I linked the step 2 version.  The completed step 3 version with that line is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676795.aspx#view_codexaml